Create permission set in test class
Let's say there is a need to create Permission Set like
PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet();
ps.Label = 'dummy-test';
ps.name = 'dummy_test';
insert ps;

inside @TestSetup method. Can be we sure that after Test.stopTest() it will be removed like e.g. Account records or CustomObject records?

When you create a PermissionSet inside a @TestSetup method, it will not be automatically removed after Test.stopTest(). The Test.stopTest() method is used to reset governor limits and execute any asynchronous code synchronously, but it does not clean up the data created during the test.
You will need to manually delete the test data if necessary.
Example:
@isTest
private class PermissionSetTest {
        @TestSetup
        static void setup() {
                PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet();
                ps.Label = 'dummy-test';
                ps.Name = 'dummy_test';
                insert ps;
        }

        @isTest
        static void testPermissionSet() {
                Test.startTest();
                // Your test logic here
                Test.stopTest();

                PermissionSet ps = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = 'dummy_test' LIMIT 1];
                delete ps;
        }
}

For more information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm

uhh... this seems wrong (or at the very least, incomplete). Sure, Test.stopTest() doesn't clean up test data, but it absolutely should be cleaned up automatically after the test class itself is done executing all of its test methods.
